# Flash AS3: How to create one function to play sounds from different buttons?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a soundboard and I'm using actionscript. I would like to have one function with the code to play a different sound depending on which button is pressed. I will also be playing from the library rather than a URL. Here is some real code mixed with pseudo for what I want to do:

```
var soundEffect:SoundEffect = new SoundEffect();

sound1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent:CLICK, buttonName, playSoundEffect); //possible?

function playSoundEffect(e:Event, buttonName):void {
    soundEffect.attachSound = buttonName + ".mp3"  //pseudo code
    soundEffect.play();
}
```

The SoundEffect class is just the name I used in Linkage. I don't know the best way to change the sound that a class represents, or the best way to do this in general. Ideally I'd like to *not* create 50 different classes with 50 different sound variables and 50 functions. I'd rather each button had some sort of identifier and within the function I can use the button name or identifier to assign the appropriate sound.

Comment: I wanted to point out that there is no attachSound method for the Sound class in AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Button symbol, you could use a naming convention that encodes the class name in your button name.

So if your sound effect class name was `sfx_jump` , you would name your instance :

```
sfx_jump_btn
```

You then set your event listener like this :

```
sfx_jump_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
```

What you want to do in the clickHandler function is to first generate your className String based on the buttons name property. Then you get the Class Definition via using getDefinitionByName so that you can create an instance of the sound, the following code is how you do that :

```
public function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     var button:SimpleButton = e.target as SimpleButton;
     // use replace to clip off the _btn suffix
     var className:String = button.name.replace("_btn","");
     var SoundClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
     var newSound:Sound = new SoundClass();
     newSound.play();
}
```

You also need to add this import :

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. Since you have multiple buttons attach a property to each button like below I attached 'soundToPlay' property to sound1_btn.

```
sound1_btn.soundToPlay = "1.mp3";
sound1_btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, handleBtnClick);

function handleBtnClick( e:Event ):void{
    soundEffect.attachSound = e.target.soundToPlay;
    soundEffect.play();
}
```

Comment: There is no attachSound method for the Sound class in AS3.

Comment: His problem is not playing sound. His problem is handing click of a button via one method.

Comment: You are correct, his 'next' problem will be playing the sound.

Comment: I will be happy to answer his separate sound related question.

Comment: I'm afraid he's right, I'm a total newb here and when I tried the code it complained there was no soundToPlay property. Can this be revised to show how to add that? Assume I have NO experience with Flash!

Comment: What kind of symbol is your button ? is it a MovieClip ? or a Button ?

Comment: This answer will not work if you are using a Button symbol, only with a MovieClip as it's a dynamic class that allows for you to add a property at runtime. So, it's likely you are using a Button Symbol.

Comment: I'm using a button. Should I just change them to Movie Clip?

Comment: I changed my answer to be specifically for a button. It will also play the sound correctly so long as you set your linkage and name the buttons correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@hrehman have the answer for you, but if you button class don't have the property `soundToPlay` you could use the `name` property as an ID. and get back with the `currentTarget`property of the event.

```
sound1_btn.name = "Sound1";
sound1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent:CLICK, playSoundEffect);

function playSoundEffect(e:Event):void {
    soundEffect.attachSound = e.currentTarget.name + ".mp3";
    soundEffect.play();
}
```

Comment: There is no attachSound method for the Sound class in AS3.

Comment: I'm getting this error: "The name property of a Timeline-placed object cannot be modified."

Comment: Ok, ignore the first line. If you are having problems with the SoundEffects class, you can use the answer of @prototypical for create the Sound object correctly. Remember, you can use the `name`property to identify the linkage name of the sound.